# How to create Password Digest for ONVIF in C++?

Tags: c++, onvif

Following ONVIF documentation, the password digest for making ONVIF Soap request should be like this.

```
PasswordDigest = B64ENCODE( SHA1( B64DECODE( Nonce ) + Date + Password ) )
```

For example:

Nonce – LKqI6G/AikKCQrN0zqZFlg==

Date – 2010-09-16T07:50:45Z

Password – userpassword

Resulting Digest – tuOSpGlFlIXsozq4HFNeeGeFLEI=

Below is how I have written in C++, which resulted in an invalid user token.

```
std::string dateTime = "2022-09-10T10:10:59.000Z";
std::string nonce = "secret";
std::string password = "mypassword";
std::string str =  decode_str(nonce) + dateTime + password;
unsigned char hash[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];
SHA1((const unsigned char *) str.c_str(), strlen(str.c_str()) - 1, hash);
uint8_t * hash_ptr = hash;
std::string psswrd = encode_str(hash_ptr, sizeof(hash));

std::cout << psswrd << std::endl; // +cz8/SJS89Uee7cTjW9aiMG9CTE=
```

But the above password is invalid, resulted the request to fail after timeout.

How to create Password Digest for ONVIF in C++?

Answer (score 2):

I believe your problem is in the call to `SHA1`. The second parameter (length of the string to be hashed) is `strlen(str) - 1`, meaning you cut off the final character of the password, which will then result in an invalid hash.

Please either use the `length` function of `std::string` or `strlen` without that decrement (which does not include the `\0`).

The second 'problem' is in the string `nonce`, which is not a Base64 string at all, however I am willing to assume this to be a plain 'example value' because you do not wish you disclose your actual `nonce` value.

Comment: Have you ever made an ONVIF Soap request successfully in C++?

Comment: No. In fact, I have no idea whatsoever about it. I have merely looked at your code and found something that 'may' cause the problem.

Comment: You are right about `strlen(str) - 1`. I now have figured it out and posted as the answer to this question.

Comment: Glad to hear I was able to help, @OConnor. Please remember to accept an answer (once the system allows you to).

Answer (score 0):

Below is a valid digest password.

```
std::string dateTime = "2022-09-10T10:10:59.000Z";
std::string nonce = "secret";
std::string password = "mypassword";
std::string str = nonce + dateTime + password;
unsigned char hash[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];
SHA1((const unsigned char *) str.c_str(), str.size(), hash);
uint8_t * hash_ptr = hash;
std::string psswrd = encode_str(hash_ptr, sizeof(hash));
```